# Javascript callback to python form that redirects after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, forms

I have a python form that redirects to, depending the case, a  certain page when submitted. For tracking purposes i need to be able to get the url to which the form redirects and pass it to Google Analytics. I imagine there's a JS callback function that I could use but I can't really find a solution.

Below is a way of how I'm trying to implement this:

```
<form method="post" class="uniForm" id="subscribeform">
      <button id="download_button" name="action" class="button" type="submit" value="subscribe">{% trans "Download" %}</button>
</form>
```

The form_valid in view is doing this:

```
 def form_valid():
           if self.kwargs['slug'] == 'document1':
            return redirect('download/word/document1.pdf')
        elif self.kwargs['slug'] == 'document2':
            return redirect('download/word/document2.pdf')
```

I have tried to create a js function that would fire at form submit:

```
$("#subscribeform").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Utils.analyticsEvent({category_title: 'download', action_title:'success', callback: function(){location_url=window.location;}});
});
```

However this is not working, i can not get the url of the document to which i get redirected. Am I missing something?